# ngx-translate is not working with Angular 14

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, angular14

I am using ngx-tanslate in my angular application for internationalization.

It works well with angular 13 but not with version 14 and the Error isn't disappear

```
ERROR TypeError: logger is undefined
    updateToken pie.js:1073
    Angular 7
    RxJS 18
    setDefaultLang ngx-translate-core.mjs:370
    TranslateService ngx-translate-core.mjs:270
    TranslateService_Factory ngx-translate-core.mjs:667
    Angular 6
    TranslatePipe_Factory ngx-translate-core.mjs:16
    pipe Angular
    AccueilComponent_div_0_Template AccueilComponent.js:89
    Angular 9
    AccueilComponent_Template template.html:1
    Angular 22
    RxJS 5
    Angular 18
    RxJS 16
    getListRegion accueil.component.ts:29
    ngOnInit accueil.component.ts:23
    Angular 17
core.mjs:7644:22
```

[image]

My ngx-translate-Version is

"@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: it seems like the culprit is `getListRegion accueil.component.ts:29` from `ngOnInit accueil.component.ts:23`, what's happening there?

Comment: nothing just call service ..

Comment: What is logger? Did you updated that package version? and why Angular  is showing 7?? Did you correctly upgraded all packages ?please check that.

Comment: @RameshRajendran I added an image for the logger error and all versions are up to date